# http webserver and I/O read write on Raspberry

Tags: python, web-services, raspberry-pi, webserver

I use http webserver python script:

```
class PiFaceWebHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
    [....]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # get the port
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = int(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        port = DEFAULT_PORT

    # set up PiFace Digital
    PiFaceWebHandler.pifacedigital = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital()

    print("Starting simple PiFace web control at:\n\n"
          "\thttp://{addr}:{port}\n\n"
          "Change the output_port with:\n\n"
          "\thttp://{addr}:{port}?output_port=0xAA\n"
          .format(addr=get_my_ip(), port=port))

    # run the server
    server_address = ('', port)
    try:
        httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, PiFaceWebHandler)
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('^C received, shutting down server')
        httpd.socket.close()
```

It's working fine, but i want the script (or another one, ) check some I/O continuously, in a while loop, ie. 
And sometimes this I/O could change state with http request. 
Currently, I/O changes state on http request, but i don't find the tips to change them on external trigger (another input ie).

How can i do? Where can i code the loop test?

do I make myself clear?

Thanks,

Comment: not familiar with raspberry-pi, but it looks like your problem can be solved with event-loop and coroutines. [Here's an example that shows similar functionality](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#example-coroutine-displaying-the-current-date).

Comment: yes i understand, but the web server is running all the time [ httpd.serve_forever() ]  and i don't know how and where create a loop or something like that.

Comment: You can watch a file in event loop using [add_reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.add_reader) and run the server at the same time using event loop's `run_until_complete` \ `run_forever`.

Comment: Have you url/tuto/exemple to illustrate this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized that `http.server.HTTPServer` isn't really compatible with `asyncio`, instead, what you can do is use `handle_request()` in a while loop ([as in this example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#more-examples)) instead of `serve_forever()` and have your IO operations in the same loop.

Comment: i tried the code `while True:
  print("boucle in")
  server.handle_request()
  print("boucle out")` but the loop isn't tested continously, only 1 each http request. And I/O change must be checked all the time

Comment: yes, that's because of `HTTPServer` implementation, you should consider switching to asyncio-based server like [aiohttp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aiohttp)